# memory strategy

Tags: php, memory-management, file-get-contents, readfile

I have a few questions that I have been searching answers for.

1: Php memory allocation.

If I have a 1 megabyte variable `$img =file_get_contents('imageUrl');`

and my php memory allocation is 64 megabytes, and 100 people are accessing the script at the same time, Is that going to cause a memory allocation error?

2: How would I better save an image from a url?
I am getting a memory allocation warning...

```
if ($fileName){
    //check to make sure filename is not taken
    if(!file_exists("img/".$fileName.$fileExt)){
            $image = file_get_contents("someURL".$fileName.$fileExt);
        //check to make sure the filesize is not rediculous 8 Megabytes.
        if(strlen($image) < (8 * 1048576)){                     
            if(file_put_contents("img/".$fileName.$fileExt, $image)){
                usleep((0.25 * 1000000)); //rest 1/4 second
                    if(!image_resize("img/".$fileName.$fileExt, 202, 202, 1))die('no rezize');
            //PRETEND THERE ARE CLOSING CURLY BRACES THANKS
```

Comment: just copy it `copy('http://example.com/example.jpeg', '/example/example.jpeg');`

Comment: I will also need to make a thumbnail version...

Comment: copy first then make the thumb

Comment: I have been mulling that part over for hours... I must have had it somewhere in my mind that I needed the file_get_contents to make the thumb. But I don't. I am only sending the image_resize function a url... Hey, Thanks for the cold glass of water in my face, I obviously needed that! Only need to get the contents once. Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about the [`memory_limit`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit) configuration directive, that is a limit on the amount of memory *each script execution* can consume, so the limit is `64M` *per user* accessing concurrently, rather than `64M` total for *all users* simultaneously and you would not exceed it.  Its purpose is to prevent, for example, one script attempting to resize a giant image that requiring hundreds of Megabytes of memory to complete, or a runaway loop accumulating a big data string without terminating, not to place a cap on possible concurrent access.

This is not to say that you could not exhaust the *server's available memory* with too much concurrency on a script though. In that case, the server would likely start paging, and have a very negative effect on performance. It should not error and stop responding to requests, however.

Answer (score 1):

PHP's memory allocation is per call. In many PHP models (e.g. fcgi) one PHP process doesn't know about the others, so this is the only practical version.

So: No, this will not throw an allocation error, but it will use 100MB

To limit total memory usage, you have to limit concurrency and per-call usage in concert.